# ASP.NET MVC 2: jQuery post string is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I'm not sure what's the issue, but I'm constructing a string and trying to pass it to my Controller Action. But when the action is executed, the data is null.

JavaScript:

```
var xml = "<Request><ZipCode>92612</ZipCode></Request>";

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/GetXml",
    contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8',
    data: xml,
    success: function (result) { success(result); },
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "text"
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetXml(string data)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {    
        return View("Index", data);
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the `if`, the "data" is null. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/GetXml",
    contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8',
    data: { data: xml },
    success: function (result) { success(result); },
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "text"
});
```

Comment: He's passing a text dataType, not JSON. This will change the parameters of the request.

Comment: No matter what I do, the data is always null. I've tried using both post and ajax. No difference.

Comment: @dcolumbus: I have edited my answer. I wrote so fast and forgot to add the variable name. The default ModelBinder will do the job

Comment: @Lorenzo, any idea why I might be getting a success but my controller action isn't actually being executed?

Comment: @dcolumbus: you mean that the request will succeed but you are not able to debug in the code? You can try using Fiddler and see what's going on with the request/response

Comment: @Lorenzo, firebug tells me that there's an XML parsing error... perhaps I should not send raw XML to the controller? What's the alternative?

Comment: @dcolumbus: Have a look at this question: [Sending xml to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906971/sending-xml-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument)

Comment: @Lorenzo, what I ultimately need is to construct XML and send it to a SPROC. I thought I could just send the XML string to the controller, but apparently not... that's too easy.

Comment: @dcolumbus: Why you dont build the xml structure in the controller and simply pass the data through the network? This way: 1) you will not experience this problem, 2) Send less data through the network 3) dont tell anyone what is the exchanged data structure

Comment: @Lorenzo, this sounds like the best way. The nice thing is that I was able to construct the XML easily with jQuery. What method do you think I should pass the data? JSON? A JavaScript object?

Answer (score 2):

The answer: don't use `contentType`

Thanks to this question and answer:
[Asp.Net Mvc JQuery ajax input parameters are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558870/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-input-parameters-are-null)

Comment: I was just about to post that solution after having fiddled with the code in Visual Studio. I'm glad you got it. You'll probably also notice that you're going to need to disable request validation for the GetXml action. ASP.NET will flip a hoo-hah if you try send it a request containing raw XML.

Comment: Disable request validation? What I'm noticing is that my ajax request is giving me a success, but none of my breakpoints within the controller action are being executed. Tells me that I'm not actually getting to the action...

Comment: If you dont disable request validation I suspect that the request is handled at an higher level and rejected from the MVC framework with maybe an HTTP 500 error

Comment: @Nathan, there's obviously a problem with sending raw XML to the controller. What would be my alternative?

Comment: As I said, disable request validation. Above the GetXml action definition add `[ValidateInput(false)]`.